# What time do gold futures weekly options expire?

Tags: options, futures, gold, expiration

What time on Friday do gold futures weekly options expire?

For example, I am interested in knowing what time the `/GCV20:XCEC 1/100 AUG 20 (Wk2) /OG2Q20:XCEC 1925 CALL` option expires this Friday.

I asked my broker, and they told me that all /GC options (weekly and monthly) expire at 12:30pm CT.

However, that conflicts with information that I found on a [CME web page](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/precious/gold_contractSpecs_options.html). On that page, if you set the Type to "American Options" (monthly options), it explicitly states that "Trading terminates at 12:30 p.m. CT on the 4th last business day of the month prior to the contract month."

But if you set the Type to "Weekly Options", all it says is that "Trading terminates on Friday of the contract week." And the trading hours are "Sunday - Friday 6:00 p.m. - 5:00 p.m. (5:00 p.m. - 4:00 p.m. CT)". So that suggests to me that the weekly options expire at 4:00pm CT.

So do the gold futures weekly options expire at 12:30pm CT or 4:00pm CT on Fridays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an [FAQ](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/files/weekly-metals-options-frequently-asked-questions.pdf) about Weekly Metals Options (WMOs) published by the CME in 2014. They say:

> 6. At what time do WMOs expire?
>
> Similar to standard Metals options, the final settlement for an expiring WMO will be based upon the daily settlement price of its underlying futures contract (Gold 1:30PM EST, Silver 1:25PM EST, Copper 1:00PM EST) on the WMO's last trading day.

I'm going to assume nothing has changed since 2014, so the weekly options for gold expire at 12:30pm CT.

Edit: I verified it by trying to place an order for the contract at 12:55pm CT today, and got an error message saying that the contract was past the expiration date and could no longer be traded.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question - I'm almost certain, comex options anyway, expire, simply, "just after" the end of that trading day - just after 5pm.

The "12.30" reference you found which seems to suggest that that monthly are different, does seem strange, I don't get that.

You sure have guts if you take it that close, bravo!

Comment: I know some futures options have strange expiration times, like the /ES quarterly options expire at 8:30am CT, not 3pm CT like the other ones do. Anyway, you think there will be much liquidity on the final day of trading?

Comment: @7529 - TBH I don't know at all.  I traded the (normal) gold options (GC-12 etc); never the weekly ones.  And, I certainly never let anything get near the end. It's a good question and I have no clue.  (If you're sort of "wanting to trade gold options" I would surely stick to the normal ones, not the weekly .. but .. ??)